# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, children

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: []
        };
    }

    async getData() {
        await axios.get("https:...")
        .then((response) => {
            console.log((response));
            console.log(typeof(response)); // object
            const convertString = JSON.parse(response.data.body);
            this.setState({message: convertString});
            console.log(convertString));
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    render() {
        const obj = (this.state.message);
        console.log(obj);
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.message}
            </div>
        )
```

I get the error: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Items, Count, ScannedCount}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

console.log(convertString) gives me this:

```
Items: Array(4)
0: {key1: "value", key2: "value"}
1: {key1: "value", key2: "value"}
2: {key1: "value", key2: "value"}
3: {key1: "value", key2: "value"}
```

How should I pass the data via this.setState() if I want to render the array in a table format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response as you can see is an array of objects.You must loop throw via this array to display the data currently for example:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
        {this.state.message.map((item,i) => (
          <div key={i}> 
            <div>{item.key1}</div>
            <div>{item.key2}</div>
          </div>
        )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

on {this.state.message.map} method you loop throw inside your message array ( contains 4 objects } and every (item) has the properties that you want to display.

Comment: I get the Error: this.state.message.map is not a function

Comment: did you delete the two lines after render() ?         const obj = (this.state.message);
        console.log(obj);

Comment: with or without the 2 lines i get the same error

Comment: replace your .then line.. until the console.log(convertString) with that..

    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(messageList=> {
        this.setState({ message: messageList});